# Rework POST from Chrome for FF

Tags: javascript, post, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm now on reworking my Chrome extension for FF and fail on a POST.

For Chrome, where it works like expected, i have a background.js, which opens a code.js:

**Chrome Background.js**:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "code.js"})
});
```

**Chrome Code.js**

```
(function(d){var f=d.createElement('form');f.action='http://gtmetrix.com/analyze.html?bm';f.method='post';var i=d.createElement('input');i.type='hidden';i.name='url';i.value=document.location.href;f.appendChild(i);d.body.appendChild(f);f.submit();})(window.open().document)
```

Doing this for FF i'm trying following:

**FF Background.js:**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'http://gtmetrix.com/analyze.html?bm', function (tab) {
    browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "code.js" },});
    });
```

**FF Code.js**

```
function submitForm(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    var f = document.createElement('form');
    f.setAttribute('method','post');
    f.setAttribute('action','http://gtmetrix.com/analyze.html?bm');

    var i = document.createElement('input');
    i.setAttribute('type','hidden');
    i.setAttribute('name','url]');
    i.setAttribute('value', request.url);
    f.appendChild(i);

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
    f.submit();
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(submitForm);
```

as it mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37908997/1992004. But: after click  is nothing happen and i get no errors...

Could somebody point me into the right direction? Where is an error? Why it isn't work?

@rd3n https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CgAUmGJ8jXE2umSmVPlbExmNYMToXy-Z

**manifest.js**

```
{
 "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
 "browser_action": {
 "default_icon": {
      "16": "icon-16.png",
     "48": "icon-48.png",
     "128": "icon-128.png"
 },
 "default_title": "ext"
 },
 "name": "ext",
 "short_name": "ext",
 "description": "ext",
 "homepage_url": "https://example.de/",
 "icons": {
     "16": "icon-16.png",
     "48": "icon-48.png",
     "128": "icon-128.png" },
 "permissions": [
     "tabs",
     "http://*/*",
     "https://*/*"
 ],
 "version": "0.1",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "developer": { 
 "name": "ext", 
 "url": "https://example.com"},
"content_scripts": [
  {
  "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["submitForm.js"]
  }
] 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's strange that you get no error with the code you posted as the **FF background.js** contains syntax errors:

- Your tab creation callback is inside the createProperties object
- There is a closing curly bracket as last argument of the `executeScript` function

Your code should be:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://gtmetrix.com/analyze.html?bm'}, tab => {
        browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'code.js'});
    });
});
```

**BUT** now clicking on your extension browser action icon will open a new tab to `http://gtmetrix.com/analyze.html?bm` and inject your `code.js` file to this page.
Then nothing will append as in your **FF code.js** your are registering a message handler but never send any message.

From what I can see in your code of your Chrome extension, that's not what you want to do, right :-) ?

A working solution would be:

**background.js**:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(tabToAnalyze => {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'about:blank'}, blankTab => {
        browser.tabs.executeScript(blankTab.id, {file: 'code.js', matchAboutBlank: true}, () => {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(blankTab.id, {url: tabToAnalyze.url});
        });
    });
});
```

**code.js** (unchanged, except removing the `]` in `i.setAttribute('name','url]');`):

```js
function submitForm(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    var f = document.createElement('form');
    f.setAttribute('method','post');
    f.setAttribute('action','https://gtmetrix.com/analyze.html?bm');

    var i = document.createElement('input');
    i.setAttribute('type','hidden');
    i.setAttribute('name','url');
    i.setAttribute('value', request.url);
    f.appendChild(i);

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
    f.submit();
}

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(submitForm);
```

**manifest.json**:

```js
{
    "name": "gtmetrix Analyzer Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "gtmetrix Analyzer for FF",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": ["tabs"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "16x16.png",
            "32": "32x32.png"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a detailed analyze - but the solution you named working opens just a new empty tab. I've tried this with the original JS - same effect, empty tab.

Comment: At https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript is written, that `You _can't_ inject code into the page that opens when you open a new empty tab.` Should your code nevertheless work? Sorry for doubts - i'm not a big profi:)

Comment: @Evgeniy Note the use of the `matchAboutBlank: true` I added in the `browser.tabs.executeScript` call, this attribute is also detailed in this documentation. I tested these scripts in FF and it worked as expected

Comment: i'm out of ideas - empty tab, thats all :( how could it be? I attached both files to the post - the content should be exactly as yours...

Comment: Maybe an error in your manifest.json file? Can you post it ? Also which FF version are you using? Do you have other extensions installed? [Here is a screencast](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A2-sFWN5WHxUld2dhMNsGyYBlJC9ZRAG/view?usp=sharing) of the running extension in FF 62

Comment: i use portable FF 49.0.0 without any other addon. Manifest is in updated post. Yes, i fully believe you, that it goes at your installation:) Can't just explain, why it doesn't at mine.

Comment: Any reason you are using such an old version of FF (about 2 years old)? The problem may come from there

Comment: It is true - at FF60 it runs like a charm! Thank you very much! I use FF49 because of many imacros scripts, which are running with previous imacros and FF versions. But... nevertheless i can't explain why it isn't running at 49.

Comment: That's because `matchAboutBlank` property can't only be used in FF 53 or later  ([see the compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript#Browser_compatibility))

Comment: Aha! Good to know. Do you see any workaround to reach the goal without binding to this option?